# Unable to upload a file through multipart form data from java as well as postman

Tags: java, rest, playframework

I have been trying to upload a file from java as well as postman. But I am unable to upload. The server is giving back the response as 200 Ok. But, the file is not being uploaded. 
API Details:
I have an API for uploading file as "FileExplorerController". This API has a method "upload()" to upload the files. Url to access this method is"/fileupload". The API is working fine if I upload a file through HTML UI.
But I am trying to upload using Java. I have tried using Postman as well.
I have passed the multipart form data in several ways. But unable to resolve the issue. The code is as follows.

**API - Upload - Function**

```
    public Result upload() {
    String fileName="";
    String folderPath="";
    String fileDescription="";
    String userName = "";
    StopWatch stopWatch = null;
    List<FileUploadStatusVo> fileStatus = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        stopWatch = LoggerUtil.startTime("FileExplorerController --> 
    upload() : File Upload");
        StringBuilder exceptionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Http.MultipartFormData body = 
    play.mvc.Controller.request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        Http.Context ctx = Http.Context.current();
        userName = ctx.session().get(SessionUtil.USER_NAME);
        String password = "";
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(userName)) {
            Map<String, String[]> formValues = play.mvc.Controller. 
             request().body().asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded();
            if(formValues != null) {
                if(formValues.get("userName") != null && 
        formValues.get("userName").length > 0) {
                    userName = formValues.get("userName")[0];
                }
                if(formValues.get("password") != null && 
        formValues.get("password").length > 0) {
                    password = formValues.get("password")[0];
                }
            }
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(userName) || 
        StringUtils.isBlank(password)) {
                return Envelope.ok();
            }
            UserVo userVo = userService.findUserByEmail(userName);
            boolean success = BCrypt.checkpw(password, userVo.password);
            if(!success) {
                return badRequest("Password doesn't match for the given user 
            name: "+userName);
            }
            if(userVo == null) {
                return Envelope.ok();
            }
        }
        boolean override = false;
        String fileTags="";
        boolean isPublicView = false;
        boolean isPublicDownload = false;
        boolean isPublicDelete = false;

        boolean isEmailNotification = false;
        boolean isEmailWithS3Link = false;

        List<String> viewerGroupNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> downloaderGroupNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> deleterGroupNames = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> viewerUserNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> downloaderUserNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> deleterUserNames = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> emailIds = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String, String[]> formValues =   
        play.mvc.Controller.request().body().
        asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded();

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(formValues.get("model")[0]);

        Set<String> groupNames = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> userNames = new HashSet<>();

        if(obj != null) {
            if(obj.get("override") != null) {
                override = Boolean.valueOf(obj.get("override").toString());
            }
            if(obj.get("description") != null) {
                fileDescription = obj.get("description").toString();
            }
            if(obj.get("tags") != null) {
                fileTags = obj.get("tags").toString();
            }

            if(obj.get("folderPath") != null){
                folderPath = obj.get("folderPath").toString();
            } else {
                folderPath = 
            ctx.session().get(SessionUtil.LOCAL_STORAGE_PATH);
            }


            if(obj.get("isPublicView") != null) {
                isPublicView = 
            Boolean.parseBoolean(obj.get("isPublicView").toString());
             }

            if(obj.get("isPublicDownload") != null) {
                isPublicDownload = 
            Boolean.parseBoolean(obj.get("isPublicDownload").toString());
            }

            if(obj.get("isPublicDelete") != null) {
                isPublicDelete = Boolean.parseBoolean(
            obj.get("isPublicDelete").toString());
            }

            if(obj.get("emailNotification") != null) {
                isEmailNotification = 
            Boolean.parseBoolean(obj.get("emailNotification").toString());
            }

            if(obj.get("emailWithFileAttachement") != null) {
                isEmailWithS3Link = 
            Boolean.parseBoolean(obj.get(
            "emailWithFileAttachement").toString());
            }

            if(obj.get("viewerGroupNames") != null) {
                //TODO
                if(!isPublicView) {
                    String[] namesArr = 
            (obj.get("viewerGroupNames").toString()).split(",");
                    for(String name:namesArr) {
                        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)) {
                            viewerGroupNames.add(name);
                            groupNames.add(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(obj.get("downloaderGroupNames") != null) {
                //TODO
                if(!isPublicDownload) {
                    String[] namesArr = 
            (obj.get("downloaderGroupNames").toString().split(","));
                    for(String name:namesArr){
                        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)) {
                            downloaderGroupNames.add(name);
                            groupNames.add(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(obj.get("deleteGroupNames") != null) {
                //TODO
                if(!isPublicDelete){
                    String[] namesArr = 
            (obj.get("deleteGroupNames").toString().split(","));
                    for(String name:namesArr){
                        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)) {
                            deleterGroupNames.add(name);
                            groupNames.add(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(obj.get("viewerUserNames") != null) {
                //TODO
                if(!isPublicView) {
                    String[] namesArr = 
           (obj.get("viewerUserNames").toString()).split(",");
                    for(String name:namesArr) {
                        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)) {
                            viewerUserNames.add(name);
                            userNames.add(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(obj.get("downloaderUserNames") != null) {
                //TODO
                if(!isPublicDownload) {
                    String[] namesArr = 
           (obj.get("downloaderUserNames").toString().split(","));
                    for(String name:namesArr){
                        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)) {
                            downloaderUserNames.add(name);
                            userNames.add(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(obj.get("deleteUserNames") != null) {
                //TODO
                if(!isPublicDelete){
                    String[] namesArr = 
           (obj.get("deleteUserNames").toString().split(","));
                    for(String name:namesArr){
                        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)) {
                            deleterUserNames.add(name);
                            userNames.add(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(obj.get("emailIds") != null) {
                if(isEmailWithS3Link) {
                    String[] emailIdsArr = 
            (obj.get("emailIds").toString()).split(",");
                    for(String emailId:emailIdsArr){
                        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(emailId)){
                            emailIds.add(emailId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(groupNames.size() == 0 && userNames.size() == 0){
            isEmailNotification = false;
        }

        List<Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart> files = body.getFiles();
        boolean multiUpload = false;
        if(files != null && files.size() > 1) {
            multiUpload = true;
        }
        Logger.info("Total Number of files is to be uploaded:"+ files.size() 
        +" by user: " + userName);
        int uploadCount = 0;
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> fileMasters = new ArrayList<>();
        FileMasterVo fileMasterVo = null;
        UserVo userVo = userService.findUserByEmail(userName);
        for(Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart uploadedFile: files) {
            if (uploadedFile == null) {
                return badRequest("File upload error for file " + 
        uploadedFile + " for file path: " + fileName);
            }
            uploadCount++;
            String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
            String name = uploadedFile.getFile().getName();
            Logger.info("Content Type: " + contentType);
            Logger.info("File Name: " + fileName);
            Logger.info("Name: " + name);
            Logger.info("Files Processed : "+uploadCount+"/"+files.size()+" 
            for user: "+userName);
            try {
                String extension = 
            FileUtil.getExtension(uploadedFile.getFilename()).toLowerCase();
                File renamedUploadFile = 

            FileUtil.moveTemporaryFile(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + 
             uploadedFile.getFilename(), uploadedFile.getFile());
                FileInputStream fis = new 
             FileInputStream(renamedUploadFile);
                String errorMsg = "";
                fileName = folderPath + uploadedFile.getFilename();
                fileNames.add(uploadedFile.getFilename());
                if(multiUpload) {
                    Logger.info("Attempting to upload file " + folderPath + 
                 "/" + uploadedFile.getFilename());
                    fileMasterVo = fileService.upload(folderPath,fileName, 
                  fileDescription, new Date(), fis, fis.available(), 
                  extension, override,
                            fileTags, isPublicView, isPublicDownload, 
                  isPublicDelete, viewerGroupNames, downloaderGroupNames,
                            deleterGroupNames, viewerUserNames, 
                  downloaderUserNames, 
                  deleterUserNames,userName,isEmailNotification);
                  } else if(fileName != null) {
                    Logger.info("Attempting to upload file " + fileName);
                    int index = fileName.lastIndexOf("/");
                    if (index > 1) {
                        fileMasterVo = 
                    fileService.upload(folderPath,fileName, fileDescription, 
                    new Date(), fis, fis.available(), extension, override,
                                fileTags, isPublicView, isPublicDownload, 
                    isPublicDelete, viewerGroupNames, downloaderGroupNames,
                                deleterGroupNames, viewerUserNames, 
                    downloaderUserNames,
                    deleterUserNames,userName,isEmailNotification);
                    } else {
                        errorMsg = "Root Folder MUST exist to upload any 
                       file";
                        return badRequest(errorMsg);
                    }
                    } else {
                    errorMsg = "File Name is incorrect";
                    return badRequest(errorMsg);
                }
                createFileActivityLog(
                fileMasterVo,userVo,ViewConstants.UPLOADED);
                if (fileMasterVo != null && fileMasterVo.getId() != null) {
                    fileMasters.add(fileMasterVo.getId().toString());
                }

                 } catch (Exception inEx) {
                createErrorLog(userName,fileName,inEx);
                exceptionBuilder.append("Exception occured in uploading 
                file: ");
                exceptionBuilder.append(name);
                exceptionBuilder.append(" are as follows ");
                exceptionBuilder.append(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(inEx));
                 }
                fileStatus.add(new 
                FileUploadStatusVo(uploadedFile.getFilename(), 
                fileMasterVo.getStatus()));
                }

                if(isEmailNotification){
                fileService.sendNotificationForFile(folderPath,fileNames, 
                userName, groupNames, 
                   userNames, ViewConstants.UPLOADED);
                }

               if (isEmailWithS3Link) {
            //fileService.sendFileS3Link(folderPath, emailIds, fileMasters);
            // Replacing sending S3 link with sending cdi specific link
            fileService.sendFilesLink(emailIds, fileMasters);
             }
            String exceptions = exceptionBuilder.toString();
            LoggerUtil.endTime(stopWatch);
            if(!StringUtils.isBlank(exceptions)) {
            Logger.error("Exception occured while uploading file: " + 
            fileName + " are as follows " + exceptions);
             }
             return Envelope.ok(fileStatus);
             } catch (Exception inEx) {
             createErrorLog(userName,fileName,inEx);
             return badRequest("There is a system error please contact 
             support/administrator" );
            }   }
```

**Client**

```
**Client - Program**
              multipart.addFormField("fileName",file.getAbsolutePath());
              multipart.addFormField("folderPath","D/");
              multipart.addFormField("fileDescription","Desc");
              multipart.addFormField("userName","superadmin");
              multipart.addFormField("password","admin");
              multipart.addFormField("override","false");
              multipart.addFormField("fileTags","tag");
              multipart.addFormField("isPublicView","true");
              multipart.addFormField("isPublicDownload","true");
              multipart.addFormField("isPublicDelete","false");
              multipart.addFormField("isEmailNotification","false");
              multipart.addFormField("isEmailWithS3Link","true");*/


              multipart.addFormField("file", input);
              System.out.print("SERVER REPLIED: ");

              for (String line : response)
              {
              System.out.print(line);
               }
              //   synchronize(clientFolder, uploadFolder, true);

                 }
             catch (MalformedURLException e)
             {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
             catch (IOException e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

Comment: How do you know it hasn't be uploaded ?

Comment: I am checking in DB as well as in web version.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to upload using the following code snippet.

Here "model" is a json object which contain all parameters.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder
                .create()
                .addTextBody("userName", userName)
                .addTextBody("password", passWord)
                .addBinaryBody("upload_file", new File(sourceFolder + "/" + fileName), ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"), fileName)
                .addTextBody("model", object.toString())
                .build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uploadURL);
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(post);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                logger.info("File " + file.getName() + " Successfully Uploaded At: " + destination);
            } else {
                logger.info("File Upload Unsuccessful");
            }
            logger.info("Response from server:" + response.getStatusLine());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            logger.error("Client Protocol Exception");
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
```